# Listar puntos cercanos ordenados por distancia en Mysql Spatial

Tags: mysql

Tengo punto de interés georeferenciados en una tabla

```
CREATE TABLE `poi` (
    `poiID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `location` POINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`poiID`),
    SPATIAL INDEX `location` (`location`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

El campo `location` uso campo `SPATIAL POINT` indexado para acelerar las búsquedas.

Tengo generados varios puntos de Barcelona insertados manualmente con

```
INSERT INTO `poi`(location) VALUES(POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(<lat> <lng>)'));
```

Quiero ahora crear la consulta para mostrar los puntos cercanos a una ubicación concreta.

Comment: Aquí algo que puede ayudar https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tema es que entiendes por cercanos. Veamos, primero que nada definimos un ejemplo según tu pregunta:

```
CREATE TABLE `poi` (
    `poiID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `location` POINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`poiID`),
    SPATIAL INDEX `location` (`location`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO poi(name, location) VALUES('Barcelona 1', POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(41.48459 2.175202)'));
INSERT INTO poi(name, location) VALUES('Barcelona 2', POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(41.312452 2.108002)'));
INSERT INTO poi(name, location) VALUES('Barcelona 3', POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(41.375156 2.154084)'));
INSERT INTO poi(name, location) VALUES('Calafell', POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(41.196385 1.566925)'));
INSERT INTO poi(name, location) VALUES('Tarragona', POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(41.102283 1.227722)'));
```

**Nota:** Los puntos, son puntos reales obtenidos de google maps.

Ahora bien, tenemos un punto de interés en Barcelona, por ejemplo: `POINT(41.374991 2.149186)` y queremos simplemente ordenar todos los puntos de la tabla por la "distancia", podríamos hacer como se sugiere en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36026887/6836377):

```
SELECT @punto := 'POINT(41.374991 2.149186)';
SELECT
  poiID,
  name,
  X(location) AS "latitude",
  Y(location) AS "longitude",
  GLength(LineString(location, GeomFromText(@punto)))  AS distance
FROM poi
  ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Es decir:

- Por cada punto armamos una línea entre este y el POI usando [`LineString()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_linestring)
- Luego calculamos la distancia con [`GLength()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gis-linestring-property-functions.html#function_glength)

El resultado:

```
+---+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
| 3 | Barcelona 3 | 41.375156 | 2.154084 | 0.0049007784075594946 |
+---+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
| 2 | Barcelona 2 | 41.312452 | 2.108002 | 0.07488156233012315   |
+---+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
| 1 | Barcelona 1 | 41.48459  | 2.175202 | 0.11264445417773167   |
+---+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
| 4 | Calafell    | 41.196385 | 1.566925 | 0.60903856639543      |
+---+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
| 5 | Tarragona   | 41.102283 | 1.227722 | 0.9609711528240588    |
+---+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Vemos que efectivamente la "distancia" es un número que refleja la cercanía entre dos puntos, tal como lo hemos planteado. El problema lo tienes si además lo que buscas es definir un "radio" de cercanía, es decir, los puntos cercanos serían los que están a un radio de 10 kilómetros por ejemplo. Aquí el tema es que la distancia que retorna [`GLength()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gis-linestring-property-functions.html#function_glength) es un número dentro del sistema de referencia, si quisiéramos ver los puntos dentro de un radio de 10 km podríamos usar [esta fórmula](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql):

```
SELECT
    poiID, 
    name,
    (
      6371 * acos (
      cos ( radians(X(POINTFROMTEXT(@punto))) )
      * cos( radians( X(location) ) )
      * cos( radians( Y(location) ) - radians(Y(POINTFROMTEXT(@punto))) )
      + sin ( radians(X(POINTFROMTEXT(@punto))) )
      * sin( radians( X(location) ) )
    )
) AS distance_km
FROM poi
HAVING distance_km < 10
ORDER BY distance_km
```

Salida:

```
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
| poiID | name        | distance_km         |
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
| 3     | Barcelona 3 | 0.40910330831504094 |
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
| 2     | Barcelona 2 | 7.757493953438743   |
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Ten en cuenta que es una aproximación a la distancia real, no tiene en cuenta alturas y presupone que la tierra es una esfera perfecta.

Otros contenidos que podrían interesarte:

- [People near you with MySQL](https://www.xarg.org/2009/12/people-near-you-with-mysql/)
- [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Answer (score 1):

Para el calculo de la distancia en metros puedes usar una funcion de Mysql:

```
ST_Distance_Sphere();

SELECT @punto := 'POINT(41.374991 2.149186)';
SELECT
  poiID,
  name,
  X(location) AS "latitude",
  Y(location) AS "longitude",
  ST_Distance_Sphere(location,GeomFromText(@punto)) AS metros,
  GLength(LineString(location,GeomFromText(@punto)))  AS distance
FROM poi
  ORDER BY distance ASC;
```